# Positioning and margin's in CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am currently trying to advance my skills in `CSS`, but it is not going so well at the moment haha. I am trying to `add a box next to a logo` on a `navigation bar` but when I try to vertically center the box with margin it just add's extra white space above the `navigation bar`?

Basically I just want to learn how to place items next to each other. Also if you could edit anything you see wrong that would be greatly appreciated!

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous);
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
}
#navigation-bar {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  border-bottom: 2px #2980B9 solid;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: "Righteous";
  line-height: 50px;
  left: 15px;
  color: #E74C3C;
  float: left;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu {
  width: 400px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navigation-bar">
    <div class="logo">
      Dewkatii
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to read about [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) to understand why you get the space above the navbar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope it's this that you want:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous);
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
}
#navigation-bar {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  border-bottom: 2px #2980B9 solid;
  position: fixed; 
  width:100%;
}
.logo {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: "Righteous";
  line-height: 50px;
  left: 15px;
  color: #E74C3C;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color:green
}
.menu {
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: black;
  float:left;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="navigation-bar">
      <div class="logo">
        Dewkatii
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You just need two put the logo and menu with float:left to align them to the left, leave the default position to them, and put in the order that you want. That solve your problem.

I Advise you two see this link http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ for more understanding of position elements with css

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `padding-top` in you're `#navigation-bar` and use`margin:0px auto`in you're `.menu`. It is a solution that works, there must be better

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help. Haven't changed a great deal at all.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="navigation-bar">
      <div class="logo">
        Dewkatii
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous);
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
}
#nav-wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  border-bottom: 2px #2980B9 solid;
}
#navigation-bar {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1120px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  position: relative;
  overflow: none;
}
#navigation-bar div {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: "Righteous";
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #E74C3C;
}
.menu {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```